# MySQL: Communications link failure. Last packet sent to the server was 0 ms ago

Tags: mysql, jdbc, database-connection

First let me clarify that I have already visited so many posts related to this issue of MySQL. I have tried almost all possible suggested solutions and none of them is working for me yet. :(

**Here is the list of fixes which I have already tried:**

1. The MySQL server is installed on CentOS. My Java code is correct
   since I am able to communicate with the MySQL server installed at my Windows PC.

   2. I have checked that MySQL server is running and accepting tcp connection at 0.0.0.0:3306    (So bind-address is correct)
   3. "skip-networking" is commented in /etc/my.cnf
   4. My username granted all privileges on the database I am accessing

When I have added the following to the iptables then I am getting permission error now:

-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT

java.sql.SQLException: Access DENIED for user .... 
**However, I have provided all privileges to  user@'%'  and user@localhost on the database I am using.**

Can anyone please suggest what could be possible error?

Here is the stacktrace of the problem.

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

Last packet sent to the server was 0 ms ago.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1074)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2104)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:729)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:302)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:283)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at com.tfv.gwj.DBResultsJson.getJsonResult(DBResultsJson.java:51)
    at com.tfv.gwj.DBResultsJson.main(DBResultsJson.java:173)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:256)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:276)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2027)
    ... 13 more
```